# Parse: data backed up on free tier?

Tags: parse-platform, backup

I recently had an issue with the free tier of Heroku Redis where our database got wiped due to "an incident" and there was no back-up of our data.

I'm about to start using the free tier of Parse and was wondering if their free tier operates in a similar way?

Thanks in advance
J

Comment: You can maintain backup yourself by [Exporting Data from Parse](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/one-click-export/) just in case

Comment: ask parse directly for this kind of confirmation

Comment: they ask you to pose your questions on stackoverflow for their team to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, parse **doesn't** offer an automated way to backup your data, because if your app is too large to backup with queries via the REST API, it's also likely going to take a long time to export from their side and consume a good chunk of resources. Allowing all apps to perform an export in this way, automatically, on a schedule, would have a significant effect on performance for the entire platform although they do allow you to export your data, but it takes time also to do this depending on your data size and they generally email it to you.

Comment: thanks for this, the client ended up upgrading the parse plan for safety